# Debug a 403 error

Tags: php, html, forms

A simple html form on a domain with an ssl certificate (`https://www.example.com/form.html`) is defined like this:

`<form method="post" action="https://www.example.com/processForm.php">`

When I post the form I get a 403 error message

I have searched extensively for solutions. I found that:

- urls in the form content should be encoded
- there might be a permission problem to be resolved in `.htaccess`
- form `method` attribute might be incorrect
- action attribute might be erroneous (for example missing the `www.`)

I have checked each of the above and not fixed the problem.

What other reasons may exist for a 403 error?

Comment: no logs, no os/webserver details.

Comment: I wish there were logs - the php error.log only deals with 500 errors. If a log did exist, where might it be found?

Comment: and again: no os details. No webserver details. for nginx on ubuntu -  `tail -f /var/log/nginx/*.log`

Comment: I'm confused, are you getting 403 when trying to browse https://www.example.com/form.html or when trying to post to https://www.example.com/processForm.php ?

Comment: I just edited to clarify. It's when I try to post the form from form.html to processForm.php

Comment: you can find out what web server you're using with `curl -s -I www.example.com | grep Server`

Comment: My web server is Apache 2.4.18

Answer (score 0):

Your target url may required a CSRF token to prevent Cross-Site Request Forgery. Read more at https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-Site_Request_Forgery_%28CSRF%29