# Encoding url in html form content

Tags: javascript, php, html, forms

I have a form where the user inputs a url in a text input field.
For example:

```
http://www.theguardian.com/world/video/2016/may/20/there-are-no-words-to-describe-how-bad-it-is-india-endures-severe-heatwave-video
```

I use a javascript function using both `encodeURI(url)` and `encodeURIComponent(url)` so the string from the form field looks like this when it is posted:

```
http%3A%2F%2Fwww.theguardian.com%2Fworld%2Fvideo%2F2016%2Fmay%2F20%2Fthere-are-no-words-to-describe-how-bad-it-is-india-endures-severe-heatwave-video
```

However, my Apache Web Server returns a 403 error when I post the form. If I remove this input from the form, there is no problem.

What else can I do to avoid the error?

Comment: What do you mean you use ***both*** `encodeURI` and `encodeURIComponent`? Not at the same time, right?

Comment: Also, a 403 is a "forbidden" error, you should start by checking your server error logs to see what the problem was, and why the user wasn't authorized.

Comment: var x=$("#urlField").val();
x=encodeURI(x);
x=encodeURIComponent(x);
$("#urlField").val(x);

Comment: So basically you're double-encoding the string, and wondering why it won't work? Remove the `x=encodeURI(x)` part, and leave just the `x=encodeURIComponent(x);` part

Comment: Also, you shouldn't really need this at all, the value from the input is encoded automatically

Comment: @adeneo - no, 'double encoding' encoding or not encoding - all these options result in the error. Leaving the form field empty doesnt result in an error. I tested with only x=encodeURIComponent(x)

Comment: @adeneo also, there are no error messages for a 403 error on my server. For that reason I recently posted this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37624213/debug-a-403-error

Comment: `403 Forbidden` usually means an issue in .htaccess.

Comment: @Barmar So why am I able to submit my form when I omit the field including the encoded url?

Comment: Does it use `method=get`? Then the parameter is being put into the URL, and one of the rewrite rules may be rejecting it.